# SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, dbcontext

I've got this exception when trying to save changes:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name
>   'dbo.UserCacheModels'.

I've already read a lot of similar questions and in most cases the problem was in the not synchronized DB schema and DbContext.
But I think my case is different because I don't have such entity. `UserCacheModel` is just a one of the DTO classes, it's not attached to DbContext and of course there is no such table in the DB.

My DbContext is very large so I'll show simplified version:

```
public class PhotoContext : DbContext
{
    public PhotoContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<PhotoContext>(null);
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
    }

    #region DataSets

    public IDbSet<VehicleLog> VehicleLogs { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<ActivityMarker> ActivityMarkers { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

    //other datasets, but there is NO IDbSet<UserCacheModel> UserCacheModels

    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleLog>()
            .Property(x => x.UserId)
            .HasColumnName("User_Id");

        modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleLog>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.User)
            .WithMany(x => x.VehicleLogs)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>()
            .Property(x => x.WorkId)
            .HasColumnName("Work_Id");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Work)
            .WithMany(x => x.Photos)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.WorkId);

       //other configuration
    }
}
```

Any ideas how is it possible?

Comment: Please include an [mcve]. At the very least include the `DbContext` implementation you are using (ie your code).

Comment: Is `UserCacheModel` referenced as a property/relationship in one of the entities like `Photo` ? How/Where is `UserCacheModel` used?

Comment: +1 on UserCacheModel likely being referenced as a property in one or more of your entities. If it is, add a .Ignore(x => x.UserCache) *(assuming UserCache is the property name)* to any entity where you might have a reference.Though better to remove the reference and keep it in the viewmodels/dtos and keep your entities pure. Having ignored properties can be a nuisance because they can creep into Linq expressions resulting in runtime failures.

Comment: If this is EF6, the class can be identified as "entity" in many ways (having `DbSet` is just one of them). For instance, does your `UserCacheModel` derive from `UserCache` entity and is located in the same assembly? You will be quite surprised that in such case EF6 will discover it and map it automatically as "entity". Another way is public reference / collection property in some other entity as mentioned by @StevePy.

Comment: @IvanStoev `UserCacheModel` doesn't have a base class but it's located in the different location from where DbContext lives(but in the same assembly where other entities are located).

Comment: @StevePy Only one entity contains a reference to `UserCacheModel` but it's configured to be ignored.

Comment: @StevePy @Ivan Stoev I'm sorry, I've just found that one of my entities contains two properties of `UserCacheModel` type but only of them is ignored in DbContext. So I believe that's the reason. Thanks a lot. If you create an answer I'll upvote them and mark as accepted.